# my login code prints for each line in the text file im using instead of just printing one output for succesful or unsuccesful login

Tags: python, authentication

my code:

```
userlog = input("What is your username?")
passlog = input("What is your password?")
for fileread in open("accounts.txt", "r").readlines():
    file = fileread.split()
    if userlog == file[0] and passlog == file[1]:
        print("Succesfully logged in")
    elif userlog != file[0] and passlog != file[1]:
        print("Username or password is incorrect")
```

instead of printing just "Succesfully logged in" or "Username or password is incorrect" it prints "Username or password is incorrect" for all lines in the text file and when the login info is typed correct it does the same but one is replaced with "Succesfully logged in"

I don't have a single clue what to do I'm obviously pretty new to python.

Comment: Your print statements are inside a `for` loop, so one of them must be executed each time round the loop.

Comment: Even if you did want an `else` branch here (which you don't), you don't need to repeat the reversed condition again (which you're not even doing correctly). Just use `else` instead of `elif ...`, that already means *"if the previous condition was not true"*.

Comment: well if the username or password is wrong i want to repeat the login section but when i add print("Username or password is incorrect") it prints it once for every line i have in the text file and then ends/repeats

Comment: Exactly. You only want to print "...incorrect" when *none* of the lines in the file match. That means you need to check all lines first before you can possible print that. The problem is that you're printing it for each line you're checking, when you're not done checking *all* lines yet.

Comment: all you had to say is put a break after the logged in succesfully part and you wouldve been so much help about an hour ago

Comment: Understanding all the ways why your code makes no sense is probably more helpful than being handed the solution on a silver platter…

Comment: its for a school project so if it works it works... i go sleep now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following solution:

```py
    userlog = input("What is your username? ")
    passlog = input("What is your password? ")
    for fileread in open("accounts.txt", "r").readlines():
        file = fileread.split()
        if userlog == file[0] and passlog == file[1]:
            print("Successfully logged in")
            break
    else:
        print("Username or password is incorrect")
```

You should break a `for` loop if a user successfully logs in.

If whole loop completes without break `else` code will be executed.

Have a look at this link: https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause

Answer (score 0):

One addition you can have is to `break` the loop when the login is successful:

```py
userlog = input("What is your username?")
passlog = input("What is your password?")
for fileread in open("accounts.txt", "r").readlines():
    file = fileread.split()
    if userlog == file[0] and passlog == file[1]:
        print("Succesfully logged in")
        break
```